# Writing argv[] through write()

Tags: c, unix, terminal

Having a bit of a issue here. I'm trying to write out data that the user has entered into argv[1]. I have to use write() to accomplish this.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  write(1, "Your File Name:", 15);
  write(1, argv[1], 100);
  return 0;
}
```

Above is my code. What I really want to know to do is to see if its possible to simply use 1 write function which concatenates the string and variable together.

With the above function aswell, I get more then I expect when I run the command. For example If i typed in stackoverflow for argv[1] my output on screen is...

YourFileName:stackoverflowXDG_VTNR=7SSH_AGENT_PID=1733XDG_SESSION_ID=c2CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=ximSESSION=ubuntuGPG_AGam@am-GA-880GM-UD2H:~$

Shouldn't it simply display yourfilenameis:stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some use of `string.h`.

For example, `strlen` will solve your issues of printing more than desired:

```
write(1, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
```

This problem was happening because you were specifically printing `100` bytes from `argv[1]` and that's undefined behavior.

About ussing only just one `write` function, I would suggest `strcat` to concatenate the output. Your code should be something like this:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char o[100] = "Your File Name: ";
    strcat(o, argv[1]);
    write(1, o, strlen(o));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a potential security problem: the size of argv[1] may be longer than 100. It's better to check the size of argv[1] before using strcat(o, argv[1]), or use strcat(o, argv[1], sizeof(o)-strlen(o)-1);

Answer (score 1):

Another option on POSIX systems is to use [`writev()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    struct iovec str[] =
    {
        { .iov_base = "Your File Name: ", .iov_len = sizeof("Your File Name: ") - 1 },
        { .iov_base = argv[1],            .iov_len = strlen(argv[1]) },
        { .iov_base = "\n",               .iov_len = 1 },
    };
    enum { NUM_STR = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]) };

    if (writev(STDOUT_FILENO, str, NUM_STR) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write to standard output\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On second thoughts, using `printf()` is more sensible.